# divide by zero error (SSIS)

Tags: ssis, derived-column

Within SSIS I am trying to do a simple division:

```
TotalIncurredAmount / TotalPremiumAmount`
```

So I wrote the following expression in an SSIS `Derived Column` transformation:

```
TotalIncurredAmount / (ISNULL(TotalPremiumAmount) ? 1 : TotalPremiumAmount)
```

But I am still getting the divide by zero error!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obviously still returning `zero` values.

Check your `TotalPremiumAmount` column for actual `zero` values as well as`null`s and if there is any, handle them in whatever way best fits your solution.